# How to find out whether direct transfer is an option for a spousal rollover

Tags: trusts-and-estates

Let's say person #1 and person #2 are married. Person #1 has a retirement plan which is administered at company #1. Person #2 has a retirement plan which is administered at company #2. Person #1 dies, and person #2 wants to do a spousal rollover into their own retirement plan. How can person #2 find out whether the spousal rollover can be done as a direct transfer into their retirement account, rather than an indirect transfer which means person #2 gets a check that they have 60 days to deposit into their retirement account?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [Personal Finance.SE](https://money.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: As the author I am happy to delete it. Please let me know if I should.

Comment: While this might well be answered on Personal Finance, and the the OP can post it there if s/he chooses, this is a legal question and is quite appropriate here on law.se.

Comment: I have since learned that if the check  is made out to "Company #2 f b o Person #2", this is actually a direct transfer, and person #2 has 60 days to deposit it. "f b o" is "for benefit of", and this wording should be confirmed with company #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can person #2 find out whether the spousal rollover can be done as
> a direct transfer into their retirement account, rather than an
> indirect transfer which means person #2 gets a check that they have 60
> days to deposit into their retirement account?

Contact the plan administrator, sometimes called the plan trustee.

The law allows plans to permit this, but the individual plan document may or may not allow it.